how to get depth frame from from a recorded video via azure kinect dk camera?
I have some recordings which I recorded using azure kinect dk cam. I recorded using multiple sensors like IR, RGB and depth data. File format is in mkv. Now I can view those captures using kinect viewer, but cant seem to retrieve depth frames from video.
This is the kinect viewer. please help me out.
(the viewer has no option for retrieving any particular frame, I checked thoroughly).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
